# How to save the option's new values plus old value without overwrite old one

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, settings-api, options

i have just tried this

```
function myplugin_update_field_foo( $new_value, $old_value ) {
if ($newvalue !== $oldvalue && !empty($oldvalue)) {
    $newvalue = array_unique( array_merge( $newvalue, $oldvalue ) );
}
return $newvalue;
}

function myplugin_init() {
    add_filter( 'pre_update_option_ra_new_series_options', 'myplugin_update_field_foo', 10, 2 );
}

add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_init' );
```

and used this to show the result in the option page but not showing anything

```
        <?php $opt=get_option( 'ra_new_series_options', $default = false ); ?>
    <?php print_r($opt); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misspelling the variables names. You define them as `$new_value` and `$old_value` with **underscore** that you forgot about.

Except this your code working fine.

```
function myplugin_update_field_foo( $new_value, $old_value ) {
    if ($new_value !== $old_value && is_array($old_value)  && is_array($new_value)) {
        $new_value = array_unique( array_merge( $new_value, $old_value ) );
    }
    return $new_value;
}
```

To get the option you use

```
$opt = get_option( 'ra_new_series_options' );
```

You can set default value if not exists like this:

```
$opt = get_option( 'ra_new_series_options', [1, 3] );
```

Another thing that you need to make sure that the `$new_value` and the `$old_value` is type array because if one of them is not your code will break.

If you want to merge different types (array, string, integer) you can do something like this:

```
add_filter( 'pre_update_option_ra_new_series_options', 'myplugin_update_field_foo', 10, 2 );
function myplugin_update_field_foo( $new_value, $old_value ) {
    $new_value_array = [];

    // Check if array and merge if not push into the array
    if( is_array( $new_value ) ) {
        $new_value_array = array_merge( $new_value_array, $new_value );
    } else {
        array_push( $new_value_array, $new_value );
    }

    if( is_array( $old_value ) ) {
        $new_value_array = array_merge( $new_value_array, $old_value );
    } else {
        array_push( $new_value_array, $old_value );
    }

    $new_value_array = array_unique( $new_value_array );

    return $new_value_array;
}
```

Comment: i already corrrect that but it's showing the new value only the old one not merged
thanks

Comment: @AhmedRabea I notice you had a problem with the `get_option()` check my answer now.